# Elastiquent Elasticsearch in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-5

After days of searching, I have decided to come here and ask.

I have used the package before, and literally copy-pasted the code but it still wont work in this project.

I am trying to use the `Elasticquent` package for `Elasticsearch` in `laravel 5.2`.

The error I get is: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`
This is being thrown in the `/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/ClientBuilder.php` file on line `111`.

This happens whenever I try to use the package (ie: using `search`, `addAllToIndex`, etc.).

From what I can tell, the config is null, so maybe there is a setting in the `elasticquent` that I missed?

Any ideas on how to fix this?

**EDIT**

My `config/elasticquent.php` file (exact same as `vendor/elasticquent/elasticquent/src/config/elasticquent.php):

```
<?php

return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Custom Elasticsearch Client Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array will be passed to the Elasticsearch client.
    | See configuration options here:
    |
    | http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_configuration.html
    */

    'config' => [
        'hosts'     => ['localhost:9200'],
        'retries'   => 1,
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Index Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the index name that Elastiquent will use for all
    | Elastiquent models.
    */

    'default_index' => 'my_custom_index_name',

);
```

**EDIT 2**
The result to `curl -XGET localhost:9200`:

```
{
  "name" : "Mac Gargan",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.3.2",
    "build_hash" : "b9e4a6acad4008027e4038f6abed7f7dba346f94",
    "build_timestamp" : "2016-04-21T16:03:47Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.5.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

**EDIT 3**
For anyone with this issue, I didn't manage to solve it. I had to use another package `mustafaaloko/elasticquent5` found [here](https://github.com/mustafaaloko/elasticquent5)

Comment: Which version of ES are you using? Also can you show how your `elasticquent.php` file looks like?

Comment: @Val ES dev-master

Comment: Not sure what dev-master is... what do you see if you call this: `curl -XGET localhost:9200`?

Comment: @Val I get `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused`. But the "dev-master" is what the instructions on the github repo says I must do

Comment: It means your Elasticsearch search is not up and running, hence why you're getting an error. Are you sure you started ES properly?

Comment: @Val I just restarted ES. I get some JSON when I run `curl -XGET localhost:9200`. But the error still happens

Comment: Please show what you get, I'd like to know which version you're running.

Comment: @Val Question updated with result

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the dev-master branch of Elastiquent only works with ES [up to 2.1](https://github.com/elasticquent/Elasticquent/blob/master/composer.json#L24) but not 2.3.2

Comment: @Val Even ES 2.1 returns the same error

Comment: Are you really sure that your `elasticquent.php` file is properly located in `/app/config/elasticquent.php` ?

Comment: @Val yes, I am. I put it there mannually

Comment: You seem to have solved the issue. What was it?

Comment: @Val I didn't, I used a different package

Comment: What package did you go with???

Comment: @AndreF. Look at Edit 3

Comment: @Haring10 Very nice, I'm not 100% sold on that package though for the following reasons:
- That package's last update was in Dec 2015. This tells me the Owner or Contributors are close to abandoning it.
- The version control does not seem to be kept up-to-date with the latest versions of ElasticSearch which is currently in 5.X
As noted in the docs:"This is meant for use with Elasticsearch 1.x."
Where as some projects are comfortable using ES at version 2.X
- I ended up going with Plastic found here:
https://github.com/sleimanx2/plastic

It's recently updated and has an active community

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer in [Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](https://github.com/elasticquent/Elasticquent/issues/78)

> I look into source code and find the problem is that the config doesn't commit as expected, so you can clear cache and publish vendor, this work for me
>
> `php artisan config:clear
>   php artisan cache:clear
>   php artisan vendor:publish`